# How did I get a message from an employer when I'm blocking all messages and searches?

Tags: support, jobs

I got a message from an employer today on Careers. I believe I had "Block all messages and searches" checked in my contact settings.  How was I able to receive this message? Does marking not interested (or one of the sub-items) change the settings?

Comment: "I believe I had" --> Can you double check?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi i can't go back in time. It was checked when i went there after i declined. hence my 2nd question.

Comment: If you had already started contact with that person they will be able to continue to contact you even with that setting checked.  Did you apply for something from that employer, or have you started some other sort of interaction with them previously?

Comment: @Servy not at all. this is an initial contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your user history, you were searchable.  When you replied, you indicated that you were no longer looking, which then sets you to not searchable.

There is one situation where an employer may send you a message even if you set your search status to "block all searches and messages".  If an employer previously messaged you and you replied interested, then we still allow messages so that you can continue the conversation even after you remove yourself from search.

On your privacy settings page on your profile you can see the people who are still able to send you messages while blocking all messages and searches under "Advanced Privacy".  There you can individually revoke access for these employers to message you or revoke everyone's access with the button.  Once you make yourself searchable again, all revocations are removed because you've made yourself available to be messaged again.  If you'd like to prevent an employer from ever messaging you again, you have that option when replying to a message for the first time.